# Отображение информации при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Есть скрипт на сайте, который при нажатии на кнопку get balance выводит текущий баланс eth кошелька. Как сделать так, чтобы информация выводилась при загрузке страницы, а не после нажатия на кнопку

```
Token Address:
<input type="text" id="contract_address" value="0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d">
<br> Ethereum Address:
<input type="text" id="eth_address" value="0xda0aed568d9a2dbdcbafc1576fedc633d28eee9a">
<button>Get Balance</button>
<p></p>
<span id="token_name"></span>
<span id="token_amount"></span>
<span id="eth_balance"></span>

<p>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("button").click(function() {
  $("BUTTON").html("Loading");
  var token = $("#contract_address").val();
  var address = $("#eth_address").val();
  $.get("https://api.tokenbalance.com/token/" + token + "/" + address, function(data, status) {
    $("#token_name").html(data.name);
    $("#token_amount").html(data.balance + " " + data.symbol);
    $("#eth_balance").html(data.eth_balance + " ETH");
    $("BUTTON").html("Get Balance");
  }).catch(function(e) {
    alert(e.statusText+" - unknown token");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: $("button").click(... -> window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    ...
  }).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("BUTTON").html("Loading");
    var token = $("#contract_address").val();
    var address = $("#eth_address").val();
    $.get("https://api.tokenbalance.com/token/" + token + "/" + address, function(data, status) {
        $("#token_name").html(data.name);
        $("#token_amount").html(data.balance + " " + data.symbol);
        $("#eth_balance").html(data.eth_balance + " ETH");
        $("BUTTON").html("Get Balance");
    }).catch(function(e) {
        alert(e.statusText+" - unknown token");
    });
});
```